# Why we need to disable SELinux during kubernetes installation

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to configure kubernetes cluster but as per blog it's telling me to disable SELinux.
Is there any specific reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you could write all the needed policies for it to work. But the Selinux subsystem doesn’t really understand namespaces and this only barely understands containers. So if you’re already running a minimalist host OS it gets you very little added security for a great deal of complexity, most people skip it.